# Sometimes "PermissionError: [Errno 13]" in same code

Tags: python, permissions, errno

I'm using windows OS. I made a function which collects stock market data every second.

It works well but sometimes has an Error.

```
    with open(output_file, "at") as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output.csv'
```

The argument 'output_file' is not folder name and the file is not open in my window.

Although error, the 'data_bat' contents are intact.

After error, next writing works well. (sometimes has an error)

Weird thing is if it has an error, the frequency of error is increased.

what do you think is the problem?

```
def output_batch(output_file, data, data_bat, bat_size):
    data_seq = [58, 52, 46, 40, 34, 28, 22, 16, 10, 4, 1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49,
            55]
    data_bat.append(data)

    if len(data_bat) >= bat_size:
        with open(output_file, "at") as fp:
            for i in range(0, bat_size):
                fp.write((data_bat[i][0] + ","))
                for k in data_seq:
                    fp.write((data_bat[i][k] + ","))
                fp.write("\n,")
                for k in data_seq:
                    fp.write((data_bat[i][k + 1] + ","))  
                fp.write("\n,")
                for k in data_seq:
                    fp.write((data_bat[i][k + 2] + ",")) 
                fp.write("\n")
            fp.close()
        del data_bat[:] # refresh list
```

Comment: windows or unix?

Comment: i am using windows 10.

Comment: what is `output_file`?

Comment: It is a name of file in that contents will be saved. I set it 'output.csv'

Comment: @AishelRe  Make sure you don't have a Virus Scanner running